# How to add the new field in sales order item at Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sales-order

How to add the new field in sales order item at Magento 1.9.x

And save the field in the database.

Add that table field

[image]

Comment: Is it product attribute?

Comment: no.. add the custom field .. one input box